# Don't show "upvoted" state when not logged in

Tags: bug, status-completed, voting, user-interface

Now, when one is not logged in and one attempts to vote on a post, it shows the "voted" state on the clicked arrow along with the "you need to be logged in to do that" message (except *without even saying so quite as clearly as that*), which is more than a little confusing.

[image: Voting confusion]

Can the "voted" state be removed, please?

P.S. Blue across the entire network kind of clashes with Meta's "red and grey only" and Stack Overflow's "only links are blue"…

Comment: It looks like they're trying to replace the previous feedback thing that appeared on hover by actually using the voting arrows when a user isn't logged in.

Comment: @animuson: Huh, okay. Logging it seems fine, but I maintain that the active state is super-confusing :P

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This was changed a little bit ago.

Now when you vote when not logged in we record it as feedback, and if you then login using the presented form we convert it into an actual vote (provided you can vote).

We agreed that "faking" the arrow was a bit confusing, probably more so for actual unregistered users.